# Why does DisplaySwitch.exe keep popping up?

Tags: windows

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise on an HP Envy 15 laptop with and i7 processor.  I have an external monitor connected via HDMI and I also have an external keyboard attached to my laptop via usb.

At random times DisplaySwitch.exe pops up.  Today it even went into a repeating loop of bringing it up at about 20 times per second.

This has happened when I have my monitor and keyboard connected but also when I have the laptop away from my desk with nothing connected.

Sometimes after this happens, when I move my cursor to a text box, I get repeating 8's in the text box.

Comment: Sounds like a key may be stuck. Has there been any damage to the keyboard? What, if anything, can you do to get it to stop?

Comment: I've tried blowing out both my external and laptop keyboard.  To get it to stop, I usually end up selecting the mode I'm currently in but it pops back up.  For the repeating 8's, I have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting your USB Keyboard from device manager then reboot without the KB attached to USB.

Once everything is back up, plug in your USB KB again.